# how do I change what an exception does when raised?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a simulated operating system for my operating systems class. One subject that was covered is interrupts, as well as errors. I am going to make a simple case:

```
def read_instructions():
  try:
    with open('assembly.txt', 'r') as assembly:
      for line in assembly:
        status = execute_instruction(line) # this will also raise an error if instruction is invalid
  except IOError as e:
    raise IOError(1)
```

Instead of getting something like `[err 2] File Not Found]` or something along those default python lines, I want something more like this:

```
def Exceptions(e):
  """ this is meant to be a 'fake' event-vector table """
  self.controller[status] = e # all exceptions will do this
  def io_exception():
    print('failed while trying to find your file')
    # some traceback and logging shenanigans here
    shutdown_system()

  def invalid_assembly():
    print('your assembly line did not follow instruction set')
    # more traceback
    shutdown_system()

  def unimplemented():
    print("you made an error I didn't catch. You've won this round.")

  return {
    1: io_exception,
    2: invalid_assembly
  }.get(e, unimplemented)()
```

is it possible to override where the raised exceptions go, and instead have them go here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions bubble up until they hit an `except` keyword. If they make it outside of the current execution context (aka they are *untrapped*), they cause Python to print a stack trace and the message contained in the error (and usually terminate the thread that happened in).

You can most certainly extend `Exception` or any other standard error type with your own class and use `raise` on them, but you can't change how the exception system works, it's part of the language specification.

So what you should do is in your 'OS', *trap* all of the exceptions:

```
try:
    run_task() # Runs an OS task
except Exception as e:
    # Do OS exception handling here. This will trap any exception thrown by a task.
```

And then do whatever you want with that exception.

You could even define your own base exception:

```
class OSBaseException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Exception, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # any other init here
    # An OS specific method hooks here
```

that you expect all your user's exceptions to extend that provides some additional hooks that your OS's trap system expects.

The [Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/) actually provides a pretty good example on doing exactly what you are trying to do.

Note that you're going to be squashing all of the stack traces, which might be annoying for 'developers' working with your OS.

Comment: I'm not sure how the `raise` protocol eventually prints the exception's representation (e.g. with `__repr__` or `str` or something else), but you could poke function calls into those instance methods, so that upon trying to print your message as a string, it does invoke some side effect behavior. So you *can* have `raise x` do something weird based on whatever `x` is -- it's just a really bad programming idea to do it that way.

Comment: @EMS It also would still halt the OS upon raising an exception, which I imagine is really what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: this is almost exactly what I was looking for -- I knew subclassing the Exception class was along the lines of what I was trying to do, I was just missing the super part. Thank you good sir